# remove jquery for nested <div> not working

Tags: jquery, html, addremoveprograms

I have the following <-div-> nested

```
<div id="smallbox">
<ul class="nolist2 formstyle">
<li>
  <div class="span4"><strong>Vehicle Data</strong></div>
</li>
<li>
  <div class="span3"><strong>Coverage<span class="red">*</span></strong></div>
  <div class="span4"><?php echo form_dropdown('coverage',$list_coverage , set_value('coverage', $coverage),'style="width:150px"'); ?></div>
</li>
<li>
  <div class="span3"><strong>Owner<span class="red">*</span></strong></div>
  <div class="span4"><?php echo form_input($owner,'','class="pageRequired" title="Required"'); ?></div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

this <-div-> block nested will be added if button "ADD_B" push using append and add increment "no"  in class

```
<div class="smallbox1">
:
</div>
```

I tried to remove the last nested div if button "REMOVE_B" push, but not working
using

> $("#remove_b").live("click",function () {
>   $("smallbox"+no).remove();
>   });

with no is the last current number
Can anyone help me please.

thanks,
frans

Comment: live is deprecated don't use it

Answer (score 0):

You missed `.` here  $(".smallbox"+no)

```
$("#remove_b").live("click",function () { $(".smallbox"+no).remove(); });
```

and live is deprecated use `.on`

```
$("#remove_b").on('click', '#remove_b', function() { $(".smallbox"+no).remove(); });
```

Comment: [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on) isn't the same thing as [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/on), you can't just swap the names and expect it to work. See the docs for how to handle delegated events with `on`

Comment: How you're doing it currently is for direct events. `live` is for delegated events. You have to do something like `$(document).on('click', '#remove_b', function() { })`. Please, read the docs.

Comment: hi all, i still don't get the solution, which doc specifically should i read? I've managed to trap the click event, but the remove process is still not working